# Run user command before build and view in TeXstudio

Tags: compiling, texstudio, automation

I made a user command:

```
user0:Make Nomenclature with the command: makeindex -s nomencl.ist -t %.nlg -o %.nls %.nlo
```

Now every time I want to build my complete pdf with the correct nomenclature, I first have to run the user command manually before I can build. Is there any way that when I click: "build and view" that TeXstudio automatically first runs the user command and then builds the pdf?

Comment: Under `Configure TeXstudio -> Build`, you can customize the `Build & View` by clicking the spanner icon (you can find it on the right side). If you scroll down the list you should be able to find your user commands, that you can add it into the build call.

Comment: @Troy Do you want to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @guywithaproblem If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). It is the TeX.SE way of saying thank you. (This also applies for your other question(s).)

Answer (score 5):

Under `Configure TeXstudio -> Build`, you can customize the `Build & View` by clicking the spanner icon (you can find it on the right side). If you scroll down the list you should be able to find your user commands, that you can add it into the build call.

[image: settings]

[image]

Comment: But how to use user0 ?